# Sharepoint 2013: How to change date format of DateTime textbox in NewForm/EditForm?

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, formatdatetime, newforms

I have a DateTime Field "Date1" in my list. I need to set its format as "DD-MMM-YYYY" (eg: 29-Mar-2017). I achieved doing this on Display form using the FormatDatetime function in XSL:Select.
I need to change it on New/Edit forms too, when date is selected from datepicker

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible by using "Calculated Value" property of 
 "Date1" column as self referral is not allowed.

What you can do is create a new "Calculated" column and then use formula `=TEXT(Date1,"dd MMM yyyy")`. Select "Date and Time" in data type returned and use "Date only" in format.

This will solve your purpose

Comment: but this calculated column would be shown only in list view. My requirement is, whenever a date is selected is from calender, the textbox should be filled with : eg 29-Mar-2017 instead of - 29/03/2017

Comment: I don't think it's able to just change date format on default "Date and Time" column, plase read this tip http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58904/42224